# deny access to all files accept the index.php and the domain name with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My website name is: cabinets.ga

I want to deny the access to all of my folders and files in my website, so this is my code to do that:

```
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  <FilesMatch "index\.php">
  Allow from all
  </FilesMatch>
```

This code works fine if the user write the link with the index.php like that : cabinets.ga/index.php but if he write only the domain name without the index.php like that: cabinets.ga it will give him (Forbidden)

So i want that if he enter both the domain name with the index.php or without it the website display the index.php without Forbidden it.. Any help please?

Comment: You can not do it this way, there is no way to “identify” the request for `/` via the `Files` directive. If you have mod_rewrite available, then try with that: `RewriteEngine on`, second line `RewriteRule !(^|index\.php)$ - [F,L]`

Comment: You are probably looking for the `DirectoryIndex ` directive. Take a look into the documentation of the http server you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just make the filename *optional* in the regex (you don't need to use mod_rewrite). For example:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This will allow direct requests to `index.php` and also requests for the directory (no filename) ...which results in `index.php` (the `DirectoryIndex`) being served by mod_dir via an internal subrequest (which occurs later).

Note that you can't simply permit an *empty* filename (ie. `"^$"`). Whilst this allows the initial request for the bare directory, it will result in the internal subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex`, ie. `index.php` being blocked - so ultimately the request is blocked.

Note also that this allows access to *all* `index.php` files in all subdirectories and all directories that contain an `index.php` index document.

---

However, if you are on Apache 2.4 then you should be using `Require` instead, since `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` are all deprecated on Apache 2.4.

```
Require all denied
<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

---

> **UPDATE:** My website is a single page application has just an index.php page controls all of my website with jquery ajax request, so i want when the user writed any other links accept my domain name accept the domain name the htaccess will redirect the user to the domain name

It sounds like you need to implement a front-controller pattern. The simplest form is using the [`FallbackResource` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). For example:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Any requests that would otherwise result in a 404 are routed to `/index.php`. Any static resources (CSS, JS, images etc.) remain accessible and are not routed to `/index.php`.

Comment: _MrWhite: your answer is correct, but i think that my question is false, because i need that all the files which i made them Forbidden stay working on my website but only users can't see them, i think my question maybe it will be: how to redirect all files in my website to my index.php .. any help please?

Comment: What type of files are you referring to? eg. server-side PHP scripts? Or linked resources like images, CSS and JS files? "how to redirect all files in my website to my index.php" - lietrally _everything_, include images, CSS and JS? Or should static resources be allowed access?

Comment: _MrWhite : My website is a single page application has just an index.php page controls all of my website with jquery ajax request, so i want when the user writed any other links accept my domain name accept the domain name the htaccess will redirect the user to the domain name http://cabinets.ga

Comment: It sounds like you probably need to implement a front-controller pattern. I've updated my answer.

Comment: brother your update is great but the problem now that because i made with htaccess all my directories and files Forbiddens: my index.php can't enter to css files and javascript files and to all directories and files, so it just i want to hide my directories and files Forbidden to users and let my index.php can enter to these directories and use them, understood me brother?

Comment: You can't block public access to server-side resources if they are to be used by your client-side SPA. So.... the first part of my answer, whilst it's answering your initial question, is totally irrelevant now (like you said, you seemed to ask the wrong question initially). You need to remove the blocking directives.

Comment: so you told me that there is no way to block public access to server-side, but there no way to make a redirect to all files and directories to the index.php ?

Comment: "...but there no way to make a redirect to all files and directories to the index.php ?" - I didn't say that all. I gave a solution using `FallbackResource`.